etwas untersuchen vs wegen etwas ermitteln
I have heard the following sentence in https://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/sendung/tagesschau_20_uhr/video-1372590.html (01:08 min) :

Wir ermitteln unter anderem wegen Mordes ...

My understanding is the translation of this is "we are investigating, among other things, murder"
Is there a difference in meaning between this sentence and "Wir untersuchen Mord" ?

"Etwas untersuchen" is much broader and basically means "to look into something carefully, in order to find something out in a structured and organized way". It can be used similar to the English "to investigate something", but also for "to look into something", "to examine something", "to research something", "to test something" and so on. "Etwas untersuchen" can be used in just about any context.
"Wegen etwas ermitteln" has a significantly narrower scope. It's basically only used in the context of police work (maybe including other investigative bodies). I'm not a lawyer and I don't even play one on TV, but to my layman's knowledge "wegen etwas ermitteln" is technical term that has very precise implications in police procedure, criminal proceedings and the like.

"Ich habe die Entfernung zwischen A und B ermittelt." is not necessarily a criminal investigation, no?

@bakunin "Wegen etwas ermitteln" is (to my knowledge) a fixed legal / procedural phrase, where the object typically is a "Straftatbestand" (a criminal offense, codified in the pertinant laws). Of course there's the more general "etwas ermitteln" as well, but that's would be third player in this game ;)

A difference is that the police term is an intransitive verb.


Is there a difference in meaning between this sentence and "Wir untersuchen Mord" ?

Yes, there is, but it is a subtle difference.
"Untersuchen" is a transitive verb and goes with an Akkusativobjekt:

jemanden/etwas untersuchen

and means "to examine" or "to look into", also "to research". It means primarily the process of examining rather than (finding) the result.
"Ermitteln" is also a transitive verb and also goes with an Akkusativobjekt:

jemanden/etwas ermitteln

It means "to investigate" or the same as "untersuchen", but implies the finding the result:

Ich untersuche das Problem. I look into the problem.
Ich ermittle die Ursache. I find out the cause.

Especially in past tense "ermitteln" includes success:

Ich habe das Problem untersucht.

I looked into the problem, maybe successfully so, maybe not. On the other hand:

Ich habe die Ursache ermittelt.

Not only did I look into the cause but I did also find it.
"ermitteln" and the noun "Ermittlung" is also used in criminal contexts and in this case can be used without an object:

Die Polizei ermittelt. The police investigates.

but also

Die Polizei ermittelt den Fahrer. The police determines the driver. or The police finds out who the driver was.

There is also a  fixed phrase "in einer Sache ermitteln", meaning "to investigate a certain case". This is used in a strictly criminal/juridical context. Not necessarily by police, but also private investigators or the like.

"to investigate in a certain case" does not make sense in English. I think you meant "to investigate a certain case" (without the preposition "in").

@AlanEvangelista: you are right, that was a typo
